# How to ensure SQLDatabase.from_databricks method access warehouse outside databricks notebook

Tags: databricks, langchain

I am using SQLDatabase.from_databricks langchain method to connect data in unity catalog to ask question to our data sets, it works in data bricks notebook but when I try to run this as databricks workflow jobs it fails throwing below error:
AttributeError: 'DatabricksReplContext' object has no attribute 'browserHostName'

except ImportError:
200     pass
--> 202 default_host = context.browserHostName if context else None
203 if host is None:
204     host = get_from_env("host", "DATABRICKS_HOST", default_host)

I think this is because Outside of a Databricks notebook, the context object is not available, and thus the SQLDatabase.from_databricks method cannot obtain the necessary information to connect to the Databricks SQL warehouse or cluster.

I tried giving parameters in method itself and as environment variables.
but method is attempting to access the browserHostName attribute from a DatabricksReplContext object, which is not available outside of a Databricks notebook environment.
how to solve this issue? do any one of you encounter this issue and how you resolved, can you help here?